# Optimize expanding SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to do this algorithm as efficiently/quickly as possible in SQL.

```
while( numberOfResults  < DesiredResults and NotCutOffCondition){
    retrieve and store up to (DesiredResults - numberOfResults) results 
        based on radius
    expand radius
}
```

The query on radius is very basic just less than/ greater than limits. I have heard that while loops are inefficient in SQL because it's not set based but I can't think of a way to do this without one. Is there a better way? This will run on MySQL, maybe SQL Server if there are any differences in that regard that I am unaware of.

consider the following table structure

```
id int
x_position decimal indexed
y_position decimal indexed
```

I need to find the nearest n points to a given x,y position. there could be thousands of possible points within a small area but not always. Therefore I need to spiral out from a small radius. Or at least I figured that would be most efficient if I only want around 20 points on a usual query.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more details on your table(s) and your exact query involved here.

Comment: You better post table schema, sample data and desired outcome to improve your chances to get your answer.

Comment: Sorry, thought that pseudo code would be enough to answer a question of efficiency.

Comment: Can you not just use a `select top 20` query or is the calculation too complex?

Comment: That could query too many results each time. Point density won't be constant.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server here's a method of finding the nearest neighbor using expanding radius in a single query. This can be easily modified to fund k neighbors.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/isaac/archive/2008/10/23/nearest-neighbors.aspx

Comment: Excellent find. I would mark it but I don't believe Mysql supports the WITH clause. Do you know of a Mysql workaround to accomplish something similar?